# Не могу понять почему isalpha так работает

Tags: python

Я пытался написать код для проверки номера телефона на отсутствие в нём букв. Только я не понял почему код работает именно так.

Не могу понять почему этот код выводит ERROR если в строке нет алфавитных символов:

```
number = '8888'
if number.isalpha:
    print('ERROR')
```

может кто-нибудь объяснить?

Comment: Можно, кстати, использовать ключевое слово `raise`: `raise ValueError`.

Comment: блин... точно... спасибо. надо быть внимательнее

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`isalpha` - это не свойство, а метод класса `str`, и для получения результата его работы этот метод нужно вызвать. Вызов метода пишется как `объект.метод(аргументы)`, т.е. после названия метода нужны скобки (). В ином случае условие будет срабатывать всегда - потому что `number.isalpha` - это `<built-in method isalpha of str object at 0x...>` - он существует и в условии интерпретируется как True.

Также нужна замена на метод `isdigit()`. Условие `if not number.isdigit():` будет работать так, как вы ожидаете, поскольку `isalpha()` истинно, когда все символы - буквы, а `isdigit()` истинно, когда все символы - цифры.

```
number = '8888A'
if not number.isdigit():
    print('ERROR') # ERROR
```

Наглядно:

```
number = '8888'

print(number.isalpha)  # печать сведений о методе: <built-in method isalpha of str object at 0x000002C6FF71A1B0>  
print(bool(number.isalpha))  # всегда True - так воспримет условие if
print(number.isalpha())  # вызов метода и результат - False
```

Вывод

```
<built-in method isalpha of str object at 0x000002C6FF71A1B0>
True
False
```

Answer (score 3):

Вместо `if number.isalpha` должно быть `if not number.isalpha()`:

```
number = '8888'
if not number.isalpha():
    print('ERROR')
```

потому что вы хотите вывести ошибку, когда в переменной `number` **НЕТУ** только цифр.

---

*Примечание:*

`.isalpha()` - **метод**, а не свойство, потому нужны скобки.